# How did thieves get into Egyptian pyramids?

Tags: ancient-egypt, pyramids

I've heard that most of the treasures in the pyramids are supposed to have been stolen by later thieves. I wonder what was their method of getting in?

Wasn't the pyramid sealed after the Pharaoh's death? Did they break the stones to get inside, or did they use ventilation shafts to get in? Could they have some kind of construction scheme of the pyramid? Did anybody guard pyramids?

Are there any sources covering that?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the thieves entered the pyramids through tunnels. A number of these tunnels still survive, like the one used to enter the [Pyramid of Senusret III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_Senusret_III) at Dahshur.

It is believed that the robbers were probably some of the same people that built the pyramids, since they knew where the chambers were within the pyramids.

The tunnels weren't built with ventilation shafts as such. Although there are some very narrow shafts whose function remains unknown in a number of pyramids, these are far to small to allow a person to enter the pyramid.

Every pyramid had an associated [mortuary temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortuary_temple). The priests, and others who worked at these temples, would probably also have acted acted as guards for the pyramid as well.

---

A good recent book about the Egyptian pyramids is [The Complete Pyramids](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nNVsHwAACAAJ), by Mark Lehner, who is currently in charge of the Giza Plateau Mapping Project. This book covers the history, building, and use of every major pyramid of ancient Egypt in some detail.